# How to grab EMS value from a view

Tags: android

Is there a way to get minEMS of a view programmatically?

I set it in my layout file, but I need to grab this value from it somewhere in the code. I don't know how

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourviewid);
int maxEMS = v.getMaxEms();
int minEMS = v.getMinEms();
```

The methods [getMaxEms()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getMaxEms%28%29) and [getMinEms()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getMinEms%28%29) are available in Views with the EMS property, like a `TextView`.

Comment: Oh maybe  I need to down cast then! I was getting the field from table row and doing a getMinEms but no luck. So I guess I need to downcast